# Local ovf to Hyper V using Virtual Machine Converter with Powershell

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, powershell, hyper-v

Now that I want convert and import a vmware VM to Hyper V. 
My ovf file with vmdk amd mf files are located in C:\OvfHVTest2.

I used the command in powershell:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter\MvmcCmdlet.psd1"
New-MvmcVirtualMachineFromOvf -DestinationLiteralPath "C:\OvfHVTest2"
```

It gives me the following error message:

> New-MvmcVirtualMachineFromOvf : No bootable drive was found for the virtual machine . This could be due to that the
>   virtual machine does not have a valid operating system.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + New-MvmcVirtualMachineFromOvf -DestinationLiteralPath "C:\OvfHVTest2"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Accel...isioningService:HyperVProvisioningService) [New-MvmcVirtu
>      alMachineFromOvf], BootableDriveNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewMvmcVirtualMachine,Microsoft.Accelerators.Mvmc.Cmdlet.Commands.NewMvmcVirtualMachineF
>      romOvfCommand
>
> New-MvmcVirtualMachineFromOvf : One or more errors occurred. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + New-MvmcVirtualMachineFromOvf -DestinationLiteralPath "C:\OvfHVTest2"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Accel...isioningService:HyperVProvisioningService)
>   [New-MvmcVirtu    alMachineFromOvf], AggregateException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewMvmcVirtualMachine,Microsoft.Accelerators.Mvmc.Cmdlet.Commands.NewMvmcVirtualMachineF
>   romOvfCommand

The guest VM is running Windows 7 Professional SP1. Could anyone please help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this kind of error when I tried to run the conversion tool in the directory which should be the target. Try setting -DestinationLiteralPath value to something different than the current directory.